# How do I kill all subprocesses spawned by my bash script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, background-process, process-management

I have a script that looks like this. Invoked with `./myscript.sh start`

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ "$1" == "start" ]]; then
  echo "Dev start script process ID: $$"

  cd /my/path1
  yarn dev &> /my/path/logs/log1.log &
  echo "started process1 in background"
  echo "Process ID: $!"
  echo "Logging output at logs/log1.log"
  sleep 2

  cd /my/path2
  yarn start:dev &> /my/path/logs/log2.log &
  echo "started process2 in background"
  echo "Process ID: $!"
  echo "Logging output at logs/log2.log"
  sleep 2

  cd /my/path2
  yarn dev &> /my/path/logs/log3.log &
  echo "started process3 in background"
  echo "Process ID: $!"
  echo "Logging output at logs/log3.log"
elif [[ "$1" == "stop" ]]; then
  killList=`ps  | grep node | awk '{print $1}'`
  if [[ $killList != "" ]]; then
      echo $killList | xargs kill
      echo  "Processes killed: $killList"
  else
      echo "Nothing to stop"
  fi
else
  echo "Invalid argument"
fi
```

When i run `ps` after I run this script, i can see a bunch of node processes (more than 3) that I assume has been started by the `yarn dev` commands. I want to run `./myscript.sh stop` and stop all the node processes that were spawned from my previous run of ./myscript.sh start

How do I make this happen?

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried already ? Please edit OP to include the new info.

Comment: The closest I was able to get to what I want is already in the OP. It can successfully kill the current node processes spawned by my script. I started with `killall node` and was able to work it out till here (the elif block)

Comment: You want a _completely separate_ instance of the script to kill processes launched by the first instance? Or do you want to have the same script, which is still running, kill its child processes?

Comment: @terdon I want a completely separate instance of the script to kill everything launched by my first instance. My script as it currentlly is, does the latter one you described, kills all the child node processes.

Comment: So how would the script know what processes to kill? What if something else launched a `node` process? Do you just want to kill _all_ running `node` processes irrespective of who started them? Are you just looking for `killall node` or `pkill node`?

Comment: Should I save the PIDs i spawned to a file and read that to find which processes to kill?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the list of processes **directly** spawned from that `bash` and send `SIGTERM` to them:

```
pgrep -P $$ --signal SIGTERM
```

`$$` is the process number of the current bash script.

Depending on how the signal is treated by the child processes, that might or not kill the grandchild processes (and so on, recursively).

So another way to do it is to get list the whole tree of processes starting at your `bash` and then kill them.

```
pstree -A -p $$ | grep -Eow "[0-9]+" | xargs kill
```

`pstree` outputs the tree (formatted for humans), `grep` extracts the process numbers and then you do what you need to do with them, for example running `kill` for each one.

Note that with the line above `pstree` will also list the `grep` and `xargs` processes,  so you will have two `No such process` warnings from `kill`. Not sure if there is a race condition, that's just a proof of concept. You can code the right side of the pipeline to deal with the list of processes properly, filter, etc.

Comment: I tried to use the pgrep and found that it seems the signal wasn't sent to the processes. I found that it is mentioned in the man page that" --signal signal ... (pkill only.)"  https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pgrep.1.html  But the "pgrep -P $$ | xargs kill " works great for me.